# How to show Latitude / Longitude in bing maps

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

I have a silverlight application that contains Bing map.
I want when the user clicks on someplace on the map to show him the lat/long of the point where he clicked. is that possible ? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do.  I am assuming you know how to set up a [mouse handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.mouseclick.aspx) on the map.  The parameter on the handler is of type [MapMouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.mapmouseeventargs_members.aspx), which contains the ViewportPoint Property, which is just an instance of the Point object documenting where on the viewport/map the click occured.  You need to translate this viewport point to lat/long coordinates.  To do this, use the [ViewportPointToLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.viewportpointtolocation.aspx) Method on your [Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map_methods.aspx) object, which as the name implies translates your viewport point to a Location(lag/long) object.  After you get the lag/long, just show it to the user however you'd like.